# Angular2 UI-router inject service to onExit

Tags: angular

How to inject service `MyService` to function `close()` in`onExit` in UI-Router state? I use `UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: myStates })` in module configuration

```
import {MyComponent} from "../my.component";
import {MyService} from "../myservice";

export const myStates = [{
  name: 'stateName1',
  params: {
    'uid': null
  },
  views: {
    'stateName2' : {
      component : MyComponent
    }
  },
  resolve: [
    {
      token: 'data',
      deps: [MyService],
      resolveFn: resolveData
    }
  ],
  onExit: [close]
}];


export function close() {
    MyService.close();
}
```